# BX Slider slide by preview is not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mozilla, bxslider

When i slide by preview image in Mozilla its not working but in chrome its working fine. Can anyone help me???

have any idea to find issue in mozilla??

```
var $this = $(this);
    var realSlider = $this.find('.product-detailslider');
    var realThumbSlider= $this.find(".product-detailslider-pager");

    realSlider.bxSlider({
        Height: 600,
        speed:1000,
        pager:false,
        nextText:'',
        prevText:'',
        infiniteLoop:false,
        hideControlOnEnd:true,

        onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
          changeRealThumb(realThumbSlider,newIndex);
        }
    });

    if ($this.data('bxSlider')) { return; }
    realThumbSlider.bxSlider({
      maxSlides: 3,
      minSlides: 3,
      slideWidth: 110,
      slideMargin: 3,
      moveSlides: 1,
      mode: 'vertical',
      pager:false,
      speed:1000,
      infiniteLoop:false,
      hideControlOnEnd:true,
      nextText:'<img src="'+BASE_URL+'/images/arrow-down.jpg"',
      prevText:'<img src="'+BASE_URL+'/images/arrow-up.jpg"'     
    });
```

Comment: create fiddle or give live example if possible

Comment: i think its perfect example to understand my problem.
if you slide in chrome its working but not working in mozilla.
Please see this example :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486338/bx-slider-sliding-outside-captions-along-with-the-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue of bxslider js, you can check here :- https://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls/

Comment: Yes this is issue of bxslider.
i tired to search answer but not get, thanks alot